# Show Android Fragment only a single time

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

I have an android app with a main activity, a LoadingFragment, and a TryAgainFragment.

What I try to do is to display in the following order:

```
defaultView --> display LoadingFragment --> onLoadingFailed: display TryAgainFragment
```

This works.

Now if the app is showing the TryAgainFragment and the user presses the back-button the following should happen:

```
TryAgainFragment --> display defaultView
```

What actually happens:

```
TryAgainFragment --> **display LoadingFragment** --> display defaultView
```

I searched quite a while now and can't find anything...

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess when it fails, you do not need `LoadingFragment` anymore. When you open `TryAgainFragment` you can remove `LoadingFragment` before adding `TryAgainFragment`.

You can do it like below.

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(tryAgainFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit
```

Comment: If you added it to backstack remove that line of code. That should do it.either addbacktostack("") or addbacktostack(null)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I read all about popBackStack, but this easy solution did not come to my mind. Instead of add I can then do .replace (cause as barismreefe pointed out the remove should be there).

Comment: The code may not be complete. I wrote it fast just to point out the logic. Have you solved the problem?